# Tkinter how to grid() successively with oop

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm making a simple game. When I call this class I want it to place 3 widgets on the same row, but when I make a new instance I want the same group of widgets to place on the next row with the grid() method. What is the best way to do this? I'm new to programming in general, especially tkinter and OOP so any help is much appreciated (:

```
class Team:
    name = 'New team'
    players = []
    points = 0

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.btn_edit = tk.Button(master, text='Edit')
        self.btn_edit.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.lbl_teamname = tk.Label(master, text='New team')
        self.lbl_teamname.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.btn_remove = tk.Button(master, text='-')
        self.btn_remove.grid(row=1, column=2)


tk.Button(teams, text='+', command=lambda: Team(teams)).grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: Can you specify 'I want the same group of widgets to place on the next row' a little more?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I already have an answer, but to clarify: with the "same group of widgets" I meant the 3 widgets the class makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get how many rows are used in a container by `container.grid_size()` which returns (columns, rows). Then you can use the returned `rows` as the value of the `row` option of `.grid(...)`:

```py
class Team:
    name = 'New team'
    players = []
    points = 0

    def __init__(self, master):
        cols, rows = master.grid_size() # return size of grid

        self.btn_edit = tk.Button(master, text='Edit')
        self.btn_edit.grid(row=rows, column=0)

        self.lbl_teamname = tk.Label(master, text='New team')
        self.lbl_teamname.grid(row=rows, column=1)

        self.btn_remove = tk.Button(master, text='-')
        self.btn_remove.grid(row=rows, column=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new instance of the `Team` class is created, you could pass the `row` as a parameter. And then, you can use that value in the `.grid` statement.

```
class Team:
    name = 'New team'
    players = []
    points = 0

    def __init__(self, master, row):
        self.btn_edit = tk.Button(master, text='Edit')
        self.btn_edit.grid(row=row, column=0)

        self.lbl_teamname = tk.Label(master, text='New team')
        self.lbl_teamname.grid(row=row, column=1)

        self.btn_remove = tk.Button(master, text='-')
        self.btn_remove.grid(row=row, column=2)


tk.Button(teams, text='+', command=lambda: Team(teams)).grid(row=0, column=0)
```